# LinkedIn API - posting to a group or profile share returns a 401 authentication code

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I had a problem with no documented solution that I could find.  Now that I found it, I'm posting it here in the event someone runs into the same issue.

I followed the steps to authenticate with LinkedIn and get an access token, I was able to retrieve my profile information and groups that I belong to without any issue.

Next, I wanted to make a post to a group using the API.

The LinkedIn API docs show the use of `file_get_contents`, but it was not working for me.  The access token was correct, but I was receiving a `401 response`. Refer to https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples.  Because I added `ignore_errors=1`, the group post was made, but still returning a `401`.

***As reference, this was the piece of code that I had to change to resolve the `401`:***

```
$context = stream_context_create(
  array('http' => 
    array('method' =>"POST",                        
      'header'=> "Content-Type:application/json\r\n",
      'content' => $body,
      'ignore_errors' => '1'
    )
  )
);
$res = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use a library for talking with linkedin. I have made a PHP class based on the examples provided by linkedin except it uses cURL and is more object oriented. https://github.com/EJTH/SLinkedIn/blob/master/examples/share.php But thats just mine, there is many others.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution Overview**

Using the LinkedIn API to post to a group, the steps are:

Set up the URL:

```
$params = array('oauth2_access_token' => YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN);

$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{group_id}/posts?' . http_build_query($params);
```

Set the body for the POST

```
$bodyArray = array(
  'title' => $title,
  'summary' => $userMessage,
  'content' => array(
    'title' => '$title2',
    'submitted-image-url' => $pictureUrl,                
    'submitted-url' => $redirectUrl,
    'description' => $userMessage                
  )            
);
$body = json_encode($bodyArray);
```

Use `CURL` instead of `get_file_contents`  This is what I needed to change to get it working.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('x-li-format: json', "Content-Type: application/json"),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
));     

// here we execute the code and check for response code
curl_exec($curl);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
if ($http_status == "201"){
  echo date('g:i') . ' Posted to LinkedIn group <br>';
}else{
  echo date('g:i') . '<b>LinkedIn error: ' . $http_status . '</b><br>';
}
```

Comment: I am getting a LinkedIn error: 401 - any idea? best M

Comment: @mboeckle Aside from using `curl` rather than `file_get_content`, no I don't.  I spent a lot of time in LinkedIn's support forums, and it seems there are several quirks that get lumped into code 401.  You can always post a ticket on their support forum if you can't find your answer.  Good luck.